# MySQL SUM rows with same ID

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sum, mysql-workbench

I have a problem i cant seem to solve. I have two tables, **Project** and **Activity**. I am supposed to combine the total hours of activity spent on each project. A project with less than 1000 hours is not to be included.

```
Project_Nr |  Project_Name |   Total Hours |
         1 |       pro1    |        501    |
         1 |       pro1    |        501    |
         2 |       pro2    |        250    |
         3 |       pro3    |        1250   |
```

As you can see, *pro1* combined have over 1000 hours and so does *pro3*. I want the end result to print something like this.

```
Project_Nr |  Project_Name |   Total Hours |
         1 |       pro1    |        1002   |
         3 |       pro3    |        1250   |
```

This is my SQL statement so far. I keep getting the combined hours of all the projects, and not split on the Project_Nr.

```
SELECT 
   project.PK_Project_Nr, 
   project.Project_Name, 
   SUM(activity.Hours) AS Combined_Hours
FROM project
INNER JOIN activity ON project.PK_Project_Nr = activity.FK_Project_Nr 
WHERE project.PK_Project_Nr IN (1)
AND project.Project_Status = "A"
GROUP BY project.Project_Nr ASC;
```

This code only checks Project_Nr 1. I need it to go through all the different projects and check if they have combined hours of 1000 and that their status is "A" (This means that the project is ongoing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the condition from the `WHERE` clause?  And then add a `HAVING` clause for the filtering on the total hours:

```
SELECT p.PK_Project_Nr, 
       p.Project_Name, 
       SUM(a.Hours) AS Combined_Hours
FROM project p JOIN
     activity a
     ON p.PK_Project_Nr = a.FK_Project_Nr 
WHERE p.Project_Status = 'A'
GROUP BY p.Project_Nr ASC
HAVING SUM(a.Hours) >= 1000;
```

Comment: "A project with less than 1000 hours is not to be included"....append `HAVING SUM(a.Hours)>=1000`

Comment: That solved it! I did not know about the "HAVING" clause, will probably come in handy later on. Thanks alot!